# dreamweaver or java applet is not working after upgrading mac to mavericks

Tags: macos, dreamweaver, osx-mavericks

i recently have updated my system to mavericks and my dreamweaver CS6 stops working?

can anybody help

When i click it, it start jumping and no open.

i also tried with cs 5, and cs 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

if still problem exists update java SE to latest version from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html